# Cant call a method for some reason

Tags: java, methods, time, bubble-sort

im trying to do buble sorting but also measure time it took to procces, and first issue i have is that i cannot call bubbleSort method even know everything look correct to me.
My second issue is that long startTime = System.nanoTime(); shows up as not declared but i did declare on top my code.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

// Program to calculate execution time or elapsed time in Java
class Main
{
private static Scanner scan;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    // ... the code being measured starts ...

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random rand = new Random();
    int size;
    int num;
    int values[];

    System.out.println("What is the size of the array?");
    size = scan.nextInt();

    values = new int[size];
    System.out.println("The " + size + " random numbers are:");
    for(int c = 0; c < size; c++)
    {  
       num = rand.nextInt(100);
       System.out.print((values[c] = num) + " ");  
    }
      System.out.println("In order:");
      for (int count = 0; count < values.length; count++)
      System.out.println(count + " = " + bubbleSort(values[count]));
 }  

 public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr)
 {
    boolean swap;
    do
    {
       swap = false;
       int temp;
       for (int count = 0; count < arr.length - 1; count++)
       if (arr[count] > arr[count+1])
       {
          temp = arr[count];
          arr[count] = arr[count+1];
          arr[count+1] = temp;
          swap = true;


       }
     } while (swap);
       System.out.println("In order:");
       for (int count = 0; count < arr.length; count++)
              System.out.print(arr[count] + " ");
 }

 // ... the code being measured ends ...
 long endTime = System.nanoTime();
 long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
}
```

Comment: There are a few questions / issues within the code above; I posted an answer to one of the issues. I suggest you try using an IDE. It would notify you of problems right away as you're editing, including more details and suggestions for fixing each problem. Two popular IDEs for Java development are Intellij and Eclipse; both free.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is declared inside the main function, which means it will only be visible inside the main function. Try to declare it like this:

```
class Main
{
private static Scanner scan;
long startTime;

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    // ... the code being measured starts ...
[...]
```

Second problem:
You are trying to print your bubble-Function as if it was a string, but it is just a void function.

Edit:
I cleaned up your code a little:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
//import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

// Program to calculate execution time or elapsed time in Java
class Main {
    private static Scanner scan;
    static long startTime;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        // ... the code being measured starts ...
        scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Random rand = new Random();
        int size;
        int num;
        int values[];
        System.out.println("What is the size of the array?");
        size = scan.nextInt();
        values = new int[size];
        for (int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
            values[c] = rand.nextInt(100);
        }
        // print the random values
        System.out.println("The " + size + " random numbers are:");
        printValues(values);
        //Sort the array here:
        bubbleSort(values);
        //print the sorted values
        System.out.println("The " + size + " random numbers in order are:");
        printValues(values);
        // ... the code being measured ends ...
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long timeElapsed = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.print("The algorithm took " + timeElapsed + " ns to terminate.");
    }

    public static void printValues(int[] values) {
        for (int count = 0; count < values.length; count++) {
            System.out.print(values[count] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void bubbleSort(int[] arr) {
        boolean swap;
        do {
            swap = false;
            int temp;
            for (int count = 0; count < arr.length - 1; count++)
                if (arr[count] > arr[count + 1]) {
                    temp = arr[count];
                    arr[count] = arr[count + 1];
                    arr[count + 1] = temp;
                    swap = true;
                }
        } while (swap);
    }
}
```

You see, I added a printValues() function that makes it more easy to print an array. Please look at this code and try to understand it, if you have questions, you what to do! :D

Comment: Thank you so much, one problem fixed, one more left.Do you have any ideas why i cannot call bubble sort method?

Comment: If you want to print out the array after it got sorted, try looping over it and printing each value at a time.

Comment: Okay but what values i have to return if i change it from void to lets say int?

Comment: try to return int[], so that you can print the sorted array in your main. I am sorry, I have to go to bed now, it is 2am where I live. I will come back here tomorrow and see if I can do some more if you didn´t solve it by then...

Comment: There's a lot more issues here though, `#endTime` is a field, and this will be evaluated before any of your method logic is called. Secondly, the fields must be static for you to access them from a static method. Third, I would rather just do something idiomatic of `startTime; doMethod(); endTime;`, which is to say that you don't need fields at all, just measure the time before and after the method. This isn't a perfect way to measure (vs say, jmh), but it's a good rough start

Answer (score 0):

> *first issue i have is that i cannot call bubbleSort method*

The code you posted is calling your `bubbleSort` method like this:

```
System.out.println(count + " = " + bubbleSort(values[count]));
```

When I pasted it into my IDE, it shows an error. The method signature for `bubbleSort` expects an integer array – `bubbleSort(int[] arr)` – but that line above is trying to pass a single integer value.

Try passing the entire `values` array to `bubbleSort()`, not just the single value at `values[count]`. So, intead of this:

```
bubbleSort(values[count])
```

try this:

```
bubbleSort(values)
```

Separately, it isn't clear what you're intent is with the println statement – `bubbleSort()` is defined to return nothing (`void`) but you're trying to append that result in the `println()` call which is not valid syntax:

```
System.out.println(count + " = " + bubbleSort(...);
```

If you want to print something like `count = 4` each time, and separately sort `values` each pass through the loop, this would work:

```
for (int count = 0; count < values.length; count++) {
    bubbleSort(values);
    System.out.println("count = " + count);
}
```

Comment: I just made a small edit so the example is a little more sane, though the original intent is still not clear to me – OP code has `count + " = " + <void>`.

Comment: I guess the intend was printing the count and the now sorted values.